# Cannot use CTRL + X/C/V in Files on Dvorak layout

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the English Dvorak keyboard layout and I'm not able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, or <kbd>V</kbd> to manipulate files in io.elementary.files [files](/questions/tagged/files).

Hitting the QWERTY equivalents (<kbd>Q</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>) does nothing; except <kbd>Q</kbd> where <kbd>X</kbd> is, which closes the program like <kbd>Q</kbd> should. Shortcuts such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all files works. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> focuses the path bar. I can copy and paste using the Right Click menu. It is only this application which seems to have this problem.

I have completed Language Support setup. I have only English (Dvorak) listed in the Keyboard settings and the install was done in Dvorak as well. I'm using a Lenovo Y510p with kernel 4.15.0-39-lowlatency and the problem happens regardless of NVIDIA or Intel setup. I am fully updated as of 2018 Nov 18th 15:16.

Side note: I think I had this problem in [release-loki](/questions/tagged/release-loki) as well, but I wasn't really using elementary OS at the time, so I just moved on.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to check: CTRL + Z for undo works, so as far as I know it's just XCV that doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a commit a while ago to fix this but it has not been released yet.

https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/360

Comment: Thank you! That's nice to know! I had kinda given up on it and I'm not much of a coder..